# Shell built-in execution

Tags: bash, shell

I'm a little confused about the definition of a shell built-in. According to the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands), for any built-in, *the shell executes the command directly, without invoking another program*. What exactly does it mean that a "command is executed directly"? For example, let's look at the `cd` built-in:

```
$ which cd 
/usr/bin/cd
$ type cd 
cd is a shell builtin
```

Now, let's look at the non built-in`grep`:

```
$ which grep 
/usr/bin/grep
$ type grep 
grep is /usr/bin/grep
```

It appears that `cd` is a separate binary. How is executing `cd` (or any other builtin) any different than executing `grep` (or any other non-builtin)?

Comment: `cd` here is a special case because it has to be a builtin to have any useful effect at all. `/usr/bin/cd` is effectively useless, because in running as its own separate process, it changes its own directory and then exits -- but **doesn't** change the directory of the separate program which invoked it.

Comment: (...there's one minor bit of use to `/usr/bin/cd`, if we're going to be pedantic -- it determines whether you *can* change to a given directory experimentally.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some commands exist as both builtins to the shell, and as separate programs.  The `which` command (which is a separate program and not a builtin!) only finds separate programs, and will never bother with builtins.  Try `type readarray` and `which readarray` to see what happens for commands that exist only as builtins.

It is important to note that the builtin version and the external program may well differ.  In some cases, you may prefer relying on the builtin (i.e. if you know what shell your script will be used on, but are unsure which exact external version will execute), or the other way around.

You can call the external program by using its full path (this will bypass the builtin).

When calling an external program, the operating system will launch a separate process, whereas the builtin is part of the shell program itself, and will therefore have much, much lower overhead.  In many cases this overhead is insignificant, but if you are going to be executing the command many times, it may turn out to have a significant impact on the performance of your script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! That's interesting. What's the point of having these binaries lying around if they already exist as built-ins? Are they ever used?

Comment: @AlexanderKohler, you can only use a shell builtin *from the shell*. Anything that uses an `execv`-family syscall to execute other programs directly can't use shell builtins and needs an external binary.

Comment: @AlexanderKohler, ...so, `find . -exec foo {} +` will always call `foo` as an external executable, no matter whether a builtin (shell function, alias, etc) by that name also exists.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy aha! That makes sense. Thanks a lot guys :D

Comment: There are many shells available, and they differ in functionnality.  POSIX mandates many programs (external commands) to ensure compatibility among systems, and these programs may be called from contexts where shell builtins are not available (i.e. when commands are not run from a shell).  The UNIX-like OS "ecosystem" is a beast with a long history and rich layers of overlapping capabilities, not a unified architecture, so this is to be expected.

Comment: ...though `cd` has *always* been a builtin, and always has to be; `[`, by contrast, is an example of a case where this is really just a performance optimization.

Comment: Possible dumb question.. but why does `cd` *have* to be a builtin?

Comment: another good example is: `type test` -> `builtin`, `which test` -> `/bin/test`.

Comment: @AlexanderKohler Although @CharlesDuffy could probably answer more authoritatively, I see one clear reason : `cd` is used to change the current directory.  The current directory is something that is kept in memory allocated to the shell.  If `cd` were called as an external program, it would execute as a child process, and would not share memory with its parent shell.  Since one process cannot write to another process memory (this is a basic principle in the design of the OS for reasons such as reliability and security), the separate process could not change the shell's current directory.

Comment: @AlexanderKohler  On my system, I was surprised to find there actually is a `/bin/cd` binary.  I anxiously tried it with the fear in my heart of seing my understanding of processes and memory protection to come crashing down.  But it was not to be.  That command does nothing at all (no idea why it exists).  My mental model is safe for now...

Comment: So @CharlesDuffy actually answered above on the actual question! Your answers agree :) Hahaha and your sanity remains for now ;)

Comment: Heh. As a supplemental aside -- the current working directory is part of the metadata tracked by the OS for a process, rather than part of the process's own in-memory state (so a program can't change to a directory it doesn't have permissions to traverse to or otherwise get a FD handle on, even if it knows the inode number for that directory)... but the gist of the clarification given by Fred above is correct, inasmuch as programs can only change *their own* directory, not that of their parents (absent debugging functionality such as `ptrace()`).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Fred's correct answer:

I understand your confusion about builtins and external commands. The `cd` command is actually good for a little demonstration.

For example on my system, the situation is the following:

```
$ which cd    # gives no output
$ whereis cd  # again, no path found
cd:
$ type -a cd  # verifies that it's a real builtin command
cd is a shell builtin
```

This clearly shows that a `cd` command in terms of an external program is not installed on my machine. In your case, the `which cd` shows that an additional `cd` command (separate program) is installed under `/usr/bin/cd`.

Sometimes it is not clear when you type `cd` whether you're going to invoke the builtin or external command. To make sure, you really invoke the builtin `cd` command, you can execute the following:

```
$ builtin cd
```

From the help page of the builtin `cd` command:

```
$ help builtin
```

> builtin: builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]
>       Execute shell builtins.
>
> ```
> Execute SHELL-BUILTIN with arguments ARGs without performing command
> lookup.  This is useful when you wish to reimplement a shell builtin
> as a shell function, but need to execute the builtin within the function.
> ```

Now you can see how the `builtin` command can be used to enforce execution of a shell builtin command. This can be very helpful in special cases.

Furthermore, you can (it's actually obvious) expect better performance from builtin commands [[source]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html):

> In general, an external command in a script forks off a subprocess,
>   [[*](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html#FTN.AEN18102)] whereas a Bash builtin does not. For this reason, builtins execute
>   more quickly and use fewer system resources than their external
>   command equivalents.

Comment: Ooo, I was unaware of the `builtin` command. It's all making a lot more sense now. Thank you!! :)